# помогите переписать 2 функции в одну

Tags: javascript, jquery, функции

подскажите как переписать 2 эти функции в одну, они отвечают за 2 стрелки слайдера и почти идентичны, мне сказали переписать это в одну функцию то не выходит из-за барьера знаний, надеюсь на помощь.

```
function next() {
  $wrapper.animate({
    'margin-left': '-=' + w
  }, set.anim, function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.find('>li:first-child').appendTo($this);
    $this.css('margin-left', 0);
  });
}

function prev() {
  $wrapper.animate({
    'margin-left': '+=' + w
  }, set.anim, function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.find('>li:last-child').prependTo($this);
    $this.css('margin-left', 0);
  });
}
```

Comment: вынеси селектор в параметр и у тебя будет одна функция

Answer (score 1):

видимо, как-то так?

```
function move(next = true){
    let sign = next ? '-' : '+';
    let anim = {'margin-left' : `${sign}=${w}` };

    $wrapper.animate(anim,  set.anim, function(){

        if(next){
             $(this).children("li:first-child").appendTo($(this));
        }
        else $(this).children("li:last-child").prependTo($(this));


        $(this).css('margin-left', 0);
    });
}
```

Comment: похоже, но я предлагаю еще вызов объединить :)

Comment: @StrangerintheQ у тебя в коде вообще не понятно  .Почему не дружишь с пробелами или хотя бы с комментариями  ?

Comment: @ИзбытокСусликов у телефона экран узкий :)

Comment: @ИзбытокСусликов https://imgur.com/a/DWLns98

Comment: @StrangerintheQ убедил. Притензий больше нет)

Comment: @StrangerintheQ я сначала объединил, потом разъединил. не наглядно.

Comment: @teran ненагляднее не придумаешь =)

Answer (score 1):

Про читаемость в вопросе ничего нет, по этому вот, держите:

```
function next(f) { 
  let m = 'margin-left'
  $wrapper.animate({
    [m] : `${f?"-":"+"}+${w}`
  }, set.anim, function(){ 
    $(this).css(m, 0).find(`>li:${f?"fir":"la"}st-child`)[`{f?"ap":"pre"}pendTo`]($(this))
  });
}
```

Comment: Издеваетесь.. Хммм... А могли бы вы еще больше запутать?))

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko я думал над загадочной деструктуризацией но не стал

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko сделал еще немного ужаснее

Comment: Оооо! Вы мой герой - держите плюсик!